# Send test email from sandbox

Tags: email, sandbox

I'm very new to Salesforce.  However, I was asked to make some changes to an approval process. This has email sent at certain times during the process. I have a process change made that I want to test, but I can't seem to get an email out to me to help me confirm if my changes are working. I have the email set to my address, but I never get any.  I also try the "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" button on the email template that I'm using, but nothing to my inbox. I don't see any type of errors. It's tough to see if my changes are working when I can't get the email to go out. Is there any setting I don't know about or something special I need to set up (or just plain old something I could be doing wrong)?  I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions that you could offer!!

Comment: I have a similar question @ https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/212666/38191 . Set it to 'All email' but still cant work, please help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look under Setup | Email Administration | Deliverability.
 Newly created sandboxes have the default email deliverability set to "System email only."
The options are:

- No access: Prevents all outbound email to and from users.
- System email only: Allows only automatically generated emails, such
  as new user and password reset emails.
- All email: Allows all types of outbound email. Default for new,
  non-sandbox organizations.

Comment: Thanks Doug!  I had to set it at 'All email' and it works great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear that worked for you :)

Comment: This has nailed me several times, so confusing!!

Comment: I have a similar question @ https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/212666/38191 . Set it to 'All email' but still cant work, please help