# Why is it that in Spring 18, Emails from Salesforce can't reach my company's outlook inbox?

Tags: email, outlook, summer-17, spring18

I remember that **3-5 months ago** (Should be Summer '17), I am able to send emails from the "Send Test and Verify Merge Fields" button in Email Template to my company's email Outlook just fine.

I have even tried using Test Deliverability to test :

[image: Test Deliverability]

Results :

- All 32 emails are received to Gmail
- No email received to Company Outlook

Is this something to do with the recent Salesforce update? How do I get around this problem?

** **UPDATE 26 MAR** :

These are my Email Deliverability settings and still cannot reach my company's outlook

[image: Email Deliverability settings]

Comment: Why are you using the Test Deliverability for testing Email template?

Comment: Because I've tried sending via Email Template - nothing, then tried 'Mass Email Contacts' tool - nothing. So last resort was Test deliverability - still nothing.

Comment: check for Deliverability of the Org.

Comment: Yeah mine is "All email" too. I'll update my question

Comment: did you check with your email server - maybe emails from Salesforce get blocker there?

Comment: Do you get any bounce messages? The only thing that comes to my mind that has changed recently is that Salesforce has changed some things regarding their TLS 1.0 email support: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=TLS-1-0-Email-Disablement&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @Kasper I normally get bulk email digest of those external email messages to be classified under spam but I get no emails received at all. How do I check if my email client supports TLS1.0 or higher?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure. I haven't used Outlook in a while.  Do you run your own Outlook server? What version is your Outlook client, and what operating system does your client run?

Comment: No don't run my own Outlook server. Outlook 2016 32-bit, Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

if no email is going out of the org, then You should check for the Deliverability of the Org.

> **No access:** Prevents all outbound email to and from users.
>   **System email only:** Allows only automatically generated emails, such as
>   new user and password reset emails. Especially useful for controlling
>   email sent from sandboxes so that testing and development work doesn’t
>   send test emails to your users. Newly created sandboxes default to
>   System email only.
>   **All email:** Allows all types of outbound email. Default for new,
>   non-sandbox organizations. Sandboxes created before Spring ’13 default
>   to All email.

[image]

Comment: I tested using Developer Edition and Sandbox Edition too, still not receiving inbox.